# LAN computers can't access my localhost website after adding SSL cert

Tags: apache, ssl, wamp

I have WAMP running on my local host. Last week, I had no SSL setup, and on Friday for a learning experience I installed my own cert with OPENSSL. The cert is working fine now and I can access my sites locally.

The problem. Last week, other users were able to access my sites when I specified their IP addresses in the `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` file. For some reason, the people who used to be able to access the sites now get an unavailable message. I have restarted the apache services any time I make a change. I have also installed the cert on the other computers trusted stores.

Is there somewhere else that I have to specify access when I am configured with an SSL cert?

**Here's what my conf file looks like now.**

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost  #also tried ServerName myFQDN
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
        Require ip 10.40.60.194 #usersname
        Allow from 10.40.60.194 #usersname  #I added this line as a trial, I didn't have it last week.
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#
```

**The error message:**
[image]

**This is the `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf`**

```
#
# This is the Apache server configuration file providing SSL support.
# It contains the configuration directives to instruct the server how to
# serve pages over an https connection. For detailed information about these
# directives see <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html>
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config, mod_setenvif, mod_ssl,
#          socache_shmcb_module (for default value of SSLSessionCache)

#
# Pseudo Random Number Generator (PRNG):
# Configure one or more sources to seed the PRNG of the SSL library.
# The seed data should be of good random quality.
# WARNING! On some platforms /dev/random blocks if not enough entropy
# is available. This means you then cannot use the /dev/random device
# because it would lead to very long connection times (as long as
# it requires to make more entropy available). But usually those
# platforms additionally provide a /dev/urandom device which doesn't
# block. So, if available, use this one instead. Read the mod_ssl User
# Manual for more details.
#
#SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/random  512
#SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom 512
#SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/random  512
#SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 512


#
# When we also provide SSL we have to listen to the
# standard HTTP port (see above) and to the HTTPS port
#
Listen 443

##
##  SSL Global Context
##
##  All SSL configuration in this context applies both to
##  the main server and all SSL-enabled virtual hosts.
##

#   SSL Cipher Suite:
#   List the ciphers that the client is permitted to negotiate,
#   and that httpd will negotiate as the client of a proxied server.
#   See the OpenSSL documentation for a complete list of ciphers, and
#   ensure these follow appropriate best practices for this deployment.
#   httpd 2.2.30, 2.4.13 and later force-disable aNULL, eNULL and EXP ciphers,
#   while OpenSSL disabled these by default in 0.9.8zf/1.0.0r/1.0.1m/1.0.2a.
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4
SSLProxyCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4

#  By the end of 2016, only TLSv1.2 ciphers should remain in use.
#  Older ciphers should be disallowed as soon as possible, while the
#  kRSA ciphers do not offer forward secrecy.  These changes inhibit
#  older clients (such as IE6 SP2 or IE8 on Windows XP, or other legacy
#  non-browser tooling) from successfully connecting.
#
#  To restrict mod_ssl to use only TLSv1.2 ciphers, and disable
#  those protocols which do not support forward secrecy, replace
#  the SSLCipherSuite and SSLProxyCipherSuite directives above with
#  the following two directives, as soon as practical.
# SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!SSLv3:!kRSA
# SSLProxyCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!SSLv3:!kRSA

#   User agents such as web browsers are not configured for the user's
#   own preference of either security or performance, therefore this
#   must be the prerogative of the web server administrator who manages
#   cpu load versus confidentiality, so enforce the server's cipher order.
SSLHonorCipherOrder on

#   SSL Protocol support:
#   List the protocol versions which clients are allowed to connect with.
#   Disable SSLv3 by default (cf. RFC 7525 3.1.1).  TLSv1 (1.0) should be
#   disabled as quickly as practical.  By the end of 2016, only the TLSv1.2
#   protocol or later should remain in use.
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3

#   Pass Phrase Dialog:
#   Configure the pass phrase gathering process.
#   The filtering dialog program (`builtin' is an internal
#   terminal dialog) has to provide the pass phrase on stdout.
#SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

#   Inter-Process Session Cache:
#   Configure the SSL Session Cache: First the mechanism
#   to use and second the expiring timeout (in seconds).
#SSLSessionCache         "dbm:c:/Apache24/logs/ssl_scache"
SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:c:/Apache24/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

#   OCSP Stapling (requires OpenSSL 0.9.8h or later)
#
#   This feature is disabled by default and requires at least
#   the two directives SSLUseStapling and SSLStaplingCache.
#   Refer to the documentation on OCSP Stapling in the SSL/TLS
#   How-To for more information.
#
#   Enable stapling for all SSL-enabled servers:
#SSLUseStapling On

#   Define a relatively small cache for OCSP Stapling using
#   the same mechanism that is used for the SSL session cache
#   above.  If stapling is used with more than a few certificates,
#   the size may need to be increased.  (AH01929 will be logged.)
#SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:c:/Apache24/logs/ssl_stapling(32768)"

#   Seconds before valid OCSP responses are expired from the cache
#SSLStaplingStandardCacheTimeout 3600

#   Seconds before invalid OCSP responses are expired from the cache
#SSLStaplingErrorCacheTimeout 600

##
## SSL Virtual Host Context
##

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

#   General setup for the virtual host
#   DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs"
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp64\www"
ServerName www.example.com:443
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
#ErrorLog "c:/Apache24/logs/error.log"
ErrorLog "C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/logs/sslerror_log"
#TransferLog "c:/Apache24/logs/access.log"
TransferLog "C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/logs/sslaccess_log"

#   SSL Engine Switch:
#   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
SSLEngine on

#   Server Certificate:
#   Point SSLCertificateFile at a PEM encoded certificate.  If
#   the certificate is encrypted, then you will be prompted for a
#   pass phrase.  Note that a kill -HUP will prompt again.  Keep
#   in mind that if you have both an RSA and a DSA certificate you
#   can configure both in parallel (to also allow the use of DSA
#   ciphers, etc.)
#   Some ECC cipher suites (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4492.txt)
#   require an ECC certificate which can also be configured in
#   parallel.
#SSLCertificateFile "c:/Apache24/conf/server.crt"
#SSLCertificateFile "c:/Apache24/conf/server-dsa.crt"
#SSLCertificateFile "c:/Apache24/conf/server-ecc.crt"
SSLCertificateFile "C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\conf\ssl.crt\server.crt"

#   Server Private Key:
#   If the key is not combined with the certificate, use this
#   directive to point at the key file.  Keep in mind that if
#   you've both a RSA and a DSA private key you can configure
#   both in parallel (to also allow the use of DSA ciphers, etc.)
#   ECC keys, when in use, can also be configured in parallel
#SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/Apache24/conf/server.key"
#SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/Apache24/conf/server-dsa.key"
#SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/Apache24/conf/server-ecc.key"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\conf\ssl.key\server.key"

#   Server Certificate Chain:
#   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
#   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
#   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
#   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
#   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
#   certificate for convenience.
#SSLCertificateChainFile "c:/Apache24/conf/server-ca.crt"

#   Certificate Authority (CA):
#   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
#   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
#   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
#   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
#         to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
#         Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
#SSLCACertificatePath "c:/Apache24/conf/ssl.crt"
#SSLCACertificateFile "c:/Apache24/conf/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt"

#   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
#   Set the CA revocation path where to find CA CRLs for client
#   authentication or alternatively one huge file containing all
#   of them (file must be PEM encoded).
#   The CRL checking mode needs to be configured explicitly
#   through SSLCARevocationCheck (defaults to "none" otherwise).
#   Note: Inside SSLCARevocationPath you need hash symlinks
#         to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
#         Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
#SSLCARevocationPath "c:/Apache24/conf/ssl.crl"
#SSLCARevocationFile "c:/Apache24/conf/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl"
#SSLCARevocationCheck chain

#   Client Authentication (Type):
#   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
#   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
#   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
#   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
#SSLVerifyClient require
#SSLVerifyDepth  10

#   TLS-SRP mutual authentication:
#   Enable TLS-SRP and set the path to the OpenSSL SRP verifier
#   file (containing login information for SRP user accounts).
#   Requires OpenSSL 1.0.1 or newer. See the mod_ssl FAQ for
#   detailed instructions on creating this file. Example:
#   "openssl srp -srpvfile c:/Apache24/conf/passwd.srpv -add username"
#SSLSRPVerifierFile "c:/Apache24/conf/passwd.srpv"

#   Access Control:
#   With SSLRequire you can do per-directory access control based
#   on arbitrary complex boolean expressions containing server
#   variable checks and other lookup directives.  The syntax is a
#   mixture between C and Perl.  See the mod_ssl documentation
#   for more details.
#<Location />
#SSLRequire (    %{SSL_CIPHER} !~ m/^(EXP|NULL)/ \
#            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "Snake Oil, Ltd." \
#            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} in {"Staff", "CA", "Dev"} \
#            and %{TIME_WDAY} >= 1 and %{TIME_WDAY} <= 5 \
#            and %{TIME_HOUR} >= 8 and %{TIME_HOUR} <= 20       ) \
#           or %{REMOTE_ADDR} =~ m/^192\.76\.162\.[0-9]+$/
#</Location>

#   SSL Engine Options:
#   Set various options for the SSL engine.
#   o FakeBasicAuth:
#     Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
#     the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
#     user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
#     Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
#     file needs this password: `xxj31ZMTZzkVA'.
#   o ExportCertData:
#     This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
#     SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
#     server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
#     authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
#     into CGI scripts.
#   o StdEnvVars:
#     This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
#     Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
#     because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
#     useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
#     exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
#   o StrictRequire:
#     This denies access when "SSLRequireSSL" or "SSLRequire" applied even
#     under a "Satisfy any" situation, i.e. when it applies access is denied
#     and no other module can change it.
#   o OptRenegotiate:
#     This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
#     directives are used in per-directory context.
#SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "c:/Apache24/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Allow from 10.40.60.140 #ccseopv1 for testing
</Directory>

#   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
#   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
#   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
#   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
#   approach you can use one of the following variables:
#   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
#     This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
#     SSL close notify alert is sent or allowed to be received.  This violates
#     the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
#     this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
#     mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
#   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
#     This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
#     SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
#     alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
#     practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
#     this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
#     works correctly.
#   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
#   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
#   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
#   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
#   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
#   "force-response-1.0" for this.
BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

#   Per-Server Logging:
#   The home of a custom SSL log file. Use this when you want a
#   compact non-error SSL logfile on a virtual host basis.
CustomLog "C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\logs\ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It says `ServerName localhost`. Is it supposed to be default virtual host? What happens when they connect, apart from not working?

Comment: Are you _really_ certain this is a connection issue? I would expect the browsers to refuse to connect, unless users add an exception, since the SSL certificate has to be considered invalid for your setup.

Comment: Updated to include the error message. I also tried changing my `ServerName localhost` to be `ServerName [my computer FQDN]` that the other users would enter and it didn't change anything.

Comment: @arkascha I added the cert to the other computer's trusted stores if that's what you mean.

Comment: Please add the configuration of the ssl based virtual host.

Comment: Where's that located?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to see the error logs to be sure but `403 Forbidden` typically means that you haven't granted access to the client's IP address. In Apache it's as simple as adding this to the virtual host:

```
Require ip 10.40.60.194
```

... and, yes, you already show such line, but not in any SSL-enabled host, only in a non-encrypted virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# 80 is the default HTTP port (HTTPS default port is 443)
# and, of course, no SSLEngine on here
    Require ip 10.40.60.194
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    SSLEngine on
</VirtualHost>
```

The key point is that HTTP and HTTPS host are entirely different hosts.

Comment: Thank you. Is this something I have to do from scratch, or is there likely a template in my WAMP configuration somewhere? If so, do you know what file that is?

Comment: WAMP creators know nothing about what projects you're working on. Just take your existing virtual hosts and create a copy for `<VirtualHost *:443>`. But I suspect you don't even have virtual hosts and just have everything in a single web site. Then type  `Require ip 10.40.60.194` inside `<VirtualHost _default_:443>`.